# Добавление данных в БД содержащихся в одном объекте

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Используется Entity Framework, Code First.
Есть 2 модели - User и Topic. 1 пользователь может иметь несколько топиков.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
}

public class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Нужно сделать такое добавление (объекты топиков внутри объекта пользователя):

```
using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
{
    // Создаем пользователя с несколькими топиками
    User user = new User
    {
        Name = "ExampleName",
        Topics = new List<Topic>
        {
            new Topic
            {
                Title = "First topic"
            },
            new Topic
            {
                Title = "Second topic"
            },
        }
    };

    // Заносим в базу все сразу
    context.Users.AddOrUpdate(user);

    // Пройдет ли добавление? Добавятся ли топики?

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Нужно, чтобы добавился и сам пользователь и 2 его топика, не прибегая сначала к добавлению пользователя, а затем топиков по отдельности. Можно ли сделать что-то подобное, используя только `context.Users.AddOrUpdate(user);`, который также уже содержит топики?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое возможно сделать. Чтобы сработало, вам необходимо явно указать в добавляемых `Topic` связь, к какому User-у они относятся. Самый простой способ - это указать свойство `UserId` у каждого `Topic`. Даже если еще такого User-а не будет в БД, сначала он добавиться, а потом и добавятся все его связанные дочерние объекты. Тогда ваш код будет такой

```
using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
{
    int userId = 1;
    // Создаем пользователя с несколькими топиками
    User user = new User
    {
        Id = userId,
        Name = "ExampleName",
        Topics = new List<Topic>
        {
            new Topic
            {
                UserId = userId,
                Title = "First topic"
            },
            new Topic
            {
                UserId = userId, 
                Title = "Second topic"
            },
        }
    };

    // Заносим в базу все сразу
    context.Users.AddOrUpdate(user);

    // Пройдет ли добавление? Добавятся ли топики?

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```