# C# Entity Framework Вставка связанных данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть код:

```
public enum ErrorType { CodeIsMissing, ConversionCodeIsMissing, UpdateError}    
public class Dict
{
    [Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{        
    [Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{        
    public Dict Dict { get; set; }        
    public Record Record { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ErrorType Type { get; set; }        
    public bool Corrected { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Dict")]
    public string DictCode { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Record")]
    public string RecordCode { get; set; }
}
```

Допустим в базе уже есть запись объекта Dict с Code="Code1" и запись объекта Record с RecordCode="RecordCode". Теперь я хочу добавить в базу объект класса Error, у которого есть объект Dict с Code="Code1" и объект Record с RecordCode="RecordCode". При сохранение выдается ошибка "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Dicts'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Dicts'. The duplicate key value is (Code3).\r\nThe statement has been terminated." Как избежать попытки повторной вставки существующих записей?

Comment: Посмотрите вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604547/Добавление-данных-в-БД-содержащихся-в-одном-объекте/604595#604595. Ответ @Ruslan_K должен работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Теперь я хочу добавить в базу объект класса Error, у которого есть
>   объект Dict с Code="Code1" и объект Record с RecordCode="RecordCode".

попробуйте передать только коды уже имеющихся записей:

```
var myError = new Error() {
    Dict = null,     
    Record = null,
    // остальные поля
    DictCode = "Code1",
    RecordCode = "RecordCode"
}

using (MyContext myContext = new MyContext())
{
    myContext.Errors.Add(myError);
    myContext.SaveChanges();
}
```